# simple hash map with vectors in C++

Tags: c++, hashmap

I'm in my first semester of studies and as a part of my comp. science assignment I have to implement a simple hash map using vectors, but I have some problems understanding the concept.

First of all I have to implement a hash function. To avoid collisions I thought it would be better to use double hashing, as follows:

```
do {
    h = (k % m + j*(1+(k % (m-2)));
    j++;
} while ( j % m != 0 );
```

where h is the hash to be returned, k is the key and m is the size of hash_map (and a prime number; they are all of type int).

This was easy, but then I need to be able to insert or remove a pair of key and the corresponding value in the map.

The signature of the two functions should be bool, so I have to return either true or flase, and I'm guessing that I should return true when there is no element at position h in the vector. (But I have no idea why remove should be bool as well).

My problem is what to do when the insert function returns false (i.e. when there is already a key-value pair saved on position h - I implemented this as a function named find). I could obviously move it to the next free place by simply increasing j, but then the hash calculated by my hash function wouldn't tell us anymore at which place a certain key is saved, causing wrong behaviour of remove function.

Is there any good example online, that doesn't use the pre defined STD methods? (My Google behaves wierdly in the past few days and only reutrns me unuseful hits in the local language)

Comment: The wikipedia article (and probably your textbook) has a good discussion of those issues.

Comment: How big can the keys be?

Comment: Keys can be anything.

Comment: I don't get it, keys can be anything?Strings?

Comment: if you want to do this simply just chuck in the element when it collides to the next slot. When you are looking for the element you get the hash as normal then check if it has the value you want. If it doesn't you move onto the next node until you find the 1 that has your value.  

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution    

this is called lineir probing

Comment: I don't think the bucketing is the expected sollution, because the j is defined to be the sum of hashing itterations (basically how many times do we do the % operation) and collisions. We do not have any textbook,but in the slides there were some animations that we move on until we find a free slot.

Comment: ya that's called linear probing go take a look at collision resolution for that. That should point you in the right direction

Comment: @Aravind well, not anything... but they can be any primitive type. I'm solving this using templates.

Comment: ok thanks @zidsal .. what about the return type of remove/insert functions?

Comment: insert and delete should return a bool. Insert should only return false if there is no room in the hash map. Even then you could just grow the hash map. Another case in which it could return false is if the hash code you have is greater then the number of spots in the array. But this can be solved by using a mod function which you already do. With good error detection and handling you could probably get insert to always return true.

Comment: so if i understood the article on wikipedia, i should already do the checks in my hash function using the int find(const Key& k)function, and modify j accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been told to move my comment to an answer so here it is. I am presuming your get method takes the value you are looking for an argument.

so what we are going to do is a process called linear probing.

when we insert the value we hash it as normal lets say our hash value is 4

```
[x,x,x,,,x,x]
```

as we can see we can simply insert it in:

```
[x,x,x,x,,x,x]
```

however if 4 is taken when we insert it we will simply move to the next slot that is empty

```
[x,x,x,**x**,x,,x,x]
```

In linear probing if we reach the end we loop back round to the beginning until we find a slot. You shouldn't run out of space as you are using a vector which can allocate extra space when it starts getting near full capacity

this will cause problems when you are searching because the value at 4 may not be at 4 anymore (in this case its at 5). To solve this we do a little bit of a hack. Note that we still get O(1) run time complexity for inserting and retrieval as long as the load balance is below 1.

in our get method instead of returning the value in the array at 4 we are instead going to start looking for our value at 4 if its there we can return it. If not we look at the value at 5 and so on till we find the value.

in **psudo code** the new stuff looks like this

```
bool insert(value){
   h = hash(value);
   while(node[h] != null){
      h++;

      if( h = node.length){
          h = 0;
       }
   }
   node[h] = value;

  return true;
}
```

get

```
get(value){
    h = hash(value);
    roundTrip = 0; //used to see if we keep going round the hashmap

   while(true){

      if(node[h] == value)
          return node[h];

      h++;

      if( h = node.length){
          h = 0;
          roundTrip++;
       }

       if(roundTrip > 1){ //we can't find it after going round list once
          return -1;
       }
   }
}
```